# Extensions of Javascript function shorthand

Tags: javascript, function

I know it's possible to define a function this way:

`x=y=>y*y`

which corresponds to:

`function x(y){ return y*y; }`

But I was wondering, is it possible to extend this to two or more arguments?

i.e. `x=y,z=>y+z` or similar to correspond to `function x(y,z){ return y*z; }`

Is there a similar convention to the very first example that allows for two or more arguments? I know that the `x=y,z=>y+z` syntax isn't right as I get errors regarding the definitions of at least one of variables... So how can it be done, or rather... *can* it be done??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions

Comment: Note that this is an ES6 (Harmony) feature: the next version of JavaScript.  It won't work in the current Chrome/Node container...I'm not sure about other browsers (which are slowly adding ES6 features)

Comment: Thanks @EthanBrown. I'd never seen this format before and immediately tried it in chrome's console and got syntax errors and was wondering what I did wrong

Comment: Heh.  Glad I mentioned it, then.  I just checked, and it's available in the most recent version of Firefox if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes try

```
x=(z,y)=>z*y
```

haha :D 
http://jsfiddle.net/FaSv2/